# dispatch_respository for external workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have multiple workflows which performs certain tasks and each workflow has a common way for authentication so instead of running each workflow I want to create an external workflow which will do the authentication only once, perform those tasks and can run be run locally. I can't install "act" and hence i tried curl command with my github token and passed the inputs of each workflow in client payload.
While running the workflow using curl command I am getting an error for tunnel. Can I run dispatch_repository workflow from feature branch locally? If yes, what should be the syntax?